# Failed overload resolution during pack expansion

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, variadic-templates

while I was trying to make some adaptations in my code, I encountered a problem with pack expansion, where theoretically it should compile.

```
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(20,2): error C2672:  'ExpandArgs': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(17): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void `anonymous-namespace'::ExpandArgs<const char(&)[9],>(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record_ostream &,Arg)' being compiled
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(17): message :         with
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(17): message :         [
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(17): message :             Arg=const char (&)[9]
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(17): message :         ]
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(54): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void `anonymous-namespace'::ExpandArgs<const char(&)[9],std::string&>(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record_ostream &,Arg,std::string &)' being compiled
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(54): message :         with
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(54): message :         [
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(54): message :             Arg=const char (&)[9]
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(54): message :         ]
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(77): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void CustomLogger::Log<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sources::logger_mt,const char(&)[9],std::string&>(Logger &,const char (&)[9],std::string &)' being compiled
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(77): message :         with
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(77): message :         [
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(77): message :             Logger=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sources::logger_mt
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(77): message :         ]
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(88): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void sA::Log<const char(&)[9],std::string&>(const char (&)[9],std::string &)' being compiled

1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(17,1): error C2780:  'void `anonymous-namespace'::ExpandArgs(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record_ostream &,Arg &&,Args &&...)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
1>C:\Projects\PocTemplateOverloadingResolution\Source.cpp(16): message :  see declaration of '`anonymous-namespace'::ExpandArgs'
```

Code: [Link to code](https://gist.github.com/cpypro/a71900cfcd16c17a96a0e6e8be2201cd)

I are using Visual Studio 2019 (v142) 
SDK Version: 10.0.18362.0

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: When you ask a question about a code that doesn't works... please: post the code in the question (a complete but minimal code to reproduce the problem), not a link to your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone see the problem?

Not sure (sorry: no experience with boost) but...

```
template< typename Arg, typename ...Args >
void ExpandArgs(boost::log::record_ostream& stream, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    ExpandArgs(stream, std::forward< Arg >(arg));

    ExpandArgs(stream, std::forward<Args>(args)...); // SHOULD COMPILE, right?
    //ExpandArgs(stream, "xpto", std::string("xpto"));
}

template< typename Arg >
void ExpandArgs(boost::log::record_ostream& stream, Arg&& arg)
{
    stream << std::forward< Arg >(arg);
}
```

what about, when `Args...` is empty, in the "SHOULD COMPILE, right?" call?

```
ExpandArgs(stream, std::forward<Args>(args)...); // ???
```

The call become

```
ExpandArgs(stream);
```

but I don't see an `ExpandArgs()` function that receive only a stream argument.

I suppose you can add a terminal case as follows

```
void ExpandArgs (boost::log::record_ostream &)
 { }
```

to solve this problem.